# Transit API how to get all Stops served by specific route?

Tags: here-api

Want to display transit route near by location of my city, I can get it from next departure but if I want to get all Stops served by that specific route in sequence order?

Following is single object of station returned **stations/by_geocoord.json**

```
{
                "id": "400702222",
                "name": "Cosburn Ave at Woodbine Ave",
                "distance": 24,
                "duration": "PT0H0M24S",
                "x": -79.317285,
                "y": 43.696509,
                "has_board": 1,
                "country": "Canada",
                "ccode": "CAN",
                "state": "ON",
                "postal": "M4C 4G4",
                "district": "Woodbine-Lumsden",
                "street": "Woodbine Ave",
                "number": "1349",
                "city": "Toronto",
                "Transports": {
                    "Transport": [
                        {
                            "name": "87",
                            "mode": 5,
                            "dir": "West - 87A Cosburn towards Broadview Station via East York Acres",
                            "At": {
                                "textColor": "#FFFFFF",
                                "color": "#804000"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "87",
                            "mode": 5,
                            "dir": "West - 87C Cosburn towards Broadview Station",
                            "At": {
                                "textColor": "#FFFFFF",
                                "color": "#804000"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
```

How to get list of stops which are included in **dir: West - 87A Cosburn towards Broadview Station via East York Acres**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to get all the transit stations/stops within a given radius by using resource as **stations/by_geocoord**

Here is the [Source](https://developer.here.com/documentation/transit/dev_guide/topics/request-constructing.html) for the documentation.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/transit/dev_guide/topics/resource-search-geocoord.html

Comment: I got list of all stops that includes **Transport: {name, mode, dir, AT: {textColor, color}}** object right. Now I want list of all stops served by *Transport.dir*

Comment: Now you can try "stations/by_name.json" resource and can specify the name="Transport Name from previous request". https://developer.here.com/documentation/transit/dev_guide/topics/example-transit-stations-by-name.html. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: No. I want stops list i.e., from first to last served by that specific Transport['dir']. I had updated  sample object in question for better understand.